# Data roll up along with transpose

Tags: r, excel, reshape

I want to roll up at customer unique id level with each observation being transposed againt it as given below
Below is the snapshot of my data

```
basedata <- structure(list(customer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "d"), class = "factor"), obs = c(12L, 
11L, 12L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 1L)), .Names = c("customer", "obs"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Or

```
customer   obs
a          12
a          11
a          12
a          10
b          3
b          5
b          7
d          8
d          1
```

I want to convert it in the following form

```
customer    obs1    obs2    obs3    obs4
a   12  11  12  10
b   3   5   7   -
d   8   1   -   -
```

I used the following code

```
basedata$shopping <- unlist(tapply(rawdata$customer, rawdata$customer,
                        function (x) seq(1, len = length(x))))
reshape(basedata, idvar = "customer", direction = "wide")
```

It gives the following error

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , timevar) : undefined columns selected
```

How can I do it in R and excel?
Thank You

Comment: Is "basedata" the same as "rawdata"? Is that a typo in your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- structure(list(customer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "d"), class = "factor"), obs = c(12L, 
11L, 12L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 1L)), .Names = c("customer", "obs"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

I chose to use a couple of extra packages (`plyr` and `reshape2`) because I find them easier and more general to use than `reshape` from the `base` package.

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
## add observation number
x2 <- ddply(x,"customer",transform,num=1:length(customer))
## reshape
dcast(x2,customer~num,value.var="obs")
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R way, assuming `dat` is the data,

```
> s <- split(dat$obs, dat$customer)
> df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(s, function(x){ length(x) <- 4; x })))
> names(df) <- paste0('obs', seq(df))
> df
#   obs1 obs2 obs3 obs4
# a   12   11   12   10
# b    3    5    7   NA
# d    8    1   NA   NA
```

If you want the unique customer ID to be a column,

```
> df2 <- cbind(customer = rownames(df), df)
> rownames(df2) <- seq(nrow(df2))
> df2
#   customer obs1 obs2 obs3 obs4
# 1        a   12   11   12   10
# 2        b    3    5    7   NA
# 3        d    8    1   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm *assuming* that "basedata" and "rawdata" are supposed to be the same (or at least copies of each other). If that's the case, you're simply missing specifying what the `timevar` argument for `reshape` should be.

Continuing from where you left off:

```
rawdata$shopping <- unlist(tapply(rawdata$customer, rawdata$customer,
                                  function (x) seq(1, len = length(x))))
## rawdata$shopping <- with(rawdata, ave(customer, customer, FUN = seq_along))
```

Here's the actual reshaping step:

```
reshape(rawdata, idvar = "customer", timevar="shopping", direction = "wide")
#   customer obs.1 obs.2 obs.3 obs.4
# 1        a    12    11    12    10
# 5        b     3     5     7    NA
# 8        d     8     1    NA    NA
```